# Python simple loop doesnt work as intended

Tags: python, loops

i just dont undersand why it dosent work and what i need to do to fix it. the goal is to make a counting game so i any tips one a restart button would be great aswell. there is no error i just dosent get out of the first loop.

```
import random
secrectnumber = random.randint(1,100)

nummberguess = 5 

print("guess a Number between 1 and 100")

number = False     
wrongguess = True
 
while wrongguess and nummberguess>0:
      guess=input()
      print( "writte a number")
      if guess.isdigit():
        guess=int(guess)
        number = True
        wrongguess = False
      else:
        print("invalid input")
        
while number:  
    nummberguess=nummberguess-1
    if guess== secrectnumber:
        print("you did it") 
        break
    elif secrectnumber>guess:
        print("the number is higeher")
        wrongguess = True
    elif secrectnumber<guess:
        print("the number is lower")
        wrongguess = True
```

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 things wrong with your code based on what you wrote:

1. If input is not a digit, the loop will run forever. This is because the first part of the condition, `while wrongguess` is always `true` and `nummberguess>0` is also always true because you're not decrementing/incrementing it. What is that supposed to do? Terminate if number_of_guess ≥ 5? You need to add a counter to actually terminate the first loop after max number of guesses is reached or whatever the desired output may be.
2. The second while loop is redundant. It'll print the same number in `guess` if the number is not the intended secret number.

#### To rectify your code, your second chunk of the code should be within the first, without the while loop. Something like this:

```py
import random
secrectnumber = random.randint(1,100)

nummberguess = 5 

print("guess a Number between 1 and 100")

number = False     
wrongguess = True
 
while wrongguess and nummberguess>0:
      guess=input()
      print( "writte a number")
      if guess.isdigit(): 
      # this won't work for input = 31, you need to iterate the string instead and check if all characters are digits, something like this:
      # sum([x.isdigit() for x in str(guess)]) == len(guess) <-- Number, this won't work for floating point numbers because '3', '.', '1', '4' (3, 1, 4 is digit, but '.' isn't). Just something to think about
        guess=int(guess)
        number = True
        wrongguess = False
      else:
        print("invalid input")
        
      nummberguess -= 1
      if guess== secrectnumber:
          print("you did it") 
          break
      elif secrectnumber>guess:
          print("the number is higeher")
          wrongguess = True
      elif secrectnumber<guess:
          print("the number is lower")
          wrongguess = True
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done very simply as :

```
import random

secrectnumber = random.randint(1, 100)
nummberguess = 5

print("guess a Number between 1 and 100")

for i in range(nummberguess):
    guess = input()
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess = int(guess)
        if guess == secrectnumber:
            print("you did it")
            break
        elif secrectnumber > guess:
            print("the number is higeher.", end="")
            if i == nummberguess -1:
                print(" Exhausted !!!")
            else:
                print(" Try again !!!")
        elif secrectnumber < guess:
            print("the number is lower.", end="")
            if i == nummberguess -1:
                print("Exhausted !!!")
            else:
                print("Try again !!!")
```